# How to align views in the middle of another views baseline?

Tags: android, view

How do you align views relative to the "middle" part of another view?

I think it is best explained with a pic of the UI I'm trying to create in android.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

i usedthe follows code,but it still has some shortcomings: you should modify the value:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/widget"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
>
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/bullet"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:paddingRight="4dip"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:lines="4"
    android:text="hidhidihfidhfdifhdifhdifhidhfidf" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffff00"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/bullet"

     android:layout_marginLeft="50dip" />

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="#ff00ff"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/bullet"

    android:layout_marginLeft="100dip"
    android:src="@drawable/star_logo" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

@pengwang and to whom it may concern

baseline refers to line at base of any view, buttons, imageviews, or any controls. when you are using baseline property  then you are giving any id of which base you want to refer or thats the place where you want your button or any. when you switch to graphical view it'll show how it adresses baseline for which you have defined

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/iB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iB"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/relativeLayout1" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

do something like this

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchedittext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:hint="Search Events, Restaurants, Businesses"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="15dip" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/searchbtn"
        android:layout_width="40dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-50dip"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_search" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/searchbtn2"
        android:layout_width="40dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-30dip"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_search" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

For placing your view centre of your parent view you just need to specify this property
**android:gravity="center"**